# is it possible to make the expression more concise without harming understandability? all these decisions are decisions you are going to have to make

Tags: word-usage, expressions

after the antecedent

> and the goal is to give you a systematic way to think about projects,
>   everything related to deep learning. It includes how to collect your
>   data, how to label your data, how to choose an architecture, and how
>   to design a proper loss function to optimize.

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=61)

> so all these decisions are decisions you are going to have to make
>   during your projects

it seems that "all these decisions are decisions" is a little bit redundant. is it possible to make the expression more concise without harming understandability?

will "all these things are decisions you are going to have to make" be better?

Comment: I would say "You will need to make decisions for the exactly same issues during your project."

Comment: *You are going to have to make decisions based on these things during your projects.*